# JSF Pass a map in ViewScoped Bean between two pages

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have two different pages. In the first page I have a Map in a ViewScoped Bean, and in the second page there is another ViewScoped Bean that needs the Map in the first page. How can I pass the Map between the two pages?

I've thought of transforming the Map into a JSON string, and passing through `<f:viewParams>`, but that might make the url too long.

Any ideas will be appreciated!

Comment: How are those two pages interacting with each other? By a plain forward navigation? Or by a redirect navigation?

Comment: Their urls are different. So I think it's redirecting... will there be differences on this?

Comment: So the second page isn't the result of a form submit on the 1st page?

Comment: Yes it is. The results of form submit on the 1st page will be stored in the map, and on the 2nd page it will need the map.

Comment: Pass the entire map? I'm thinking whether there are any good hash functions for this sort of thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that the second page is been opened by a PRG request, your best bet is to make use of the flash scope. You can put flash scoped attributes in the map as available by  `ExternalContext#getFlash()` and you can get them in the next request by the very same `ExternalContext#getFlash()` map (which is in EL scope also available by `#{flash}`).

So, e.g. this should do: in the action method of backing bean of first page:

```
public String submit() {
    // ...

    ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    ec.getFlash().put("data", data);
    return "page2?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

And then a property of backing bean of second page (page2):

```
@ManagedProperty("#{flash.data}")
private Map<String, String> data;   // Setter required.
```

Or, alternatively, the postconstruct of backing bean of second page:

```
private Map<String, String> data;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    data = (Map<String, String>) ec.getFlash().get("data");        
}
```

Comment: I've noticed that a drawback of this method is that it affects the bookmarkability of a page since you will always rely on the previous page to pass parameters.

Comment: Then do that you initially wanted but didn't want (passing as request param).